# Derivative Simplification $u_x^2u_{xx}+uu_{xx}^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there any way of simplifying\begin{align}
u_x^2u_{xx}+uu_{xx}^2
\end{align}
into some expression of the form$$
C\left((u^a)_{xx}   \right)^b\,\,\,\,\,\text{ or }\,\,\,\,\,C\left((u_x^a)_{x}   \right)^b
$$
for some constants $a$, $b$ and $C$?

It seems impossible, but if that is the case, how do I show it is indeed impossible?

Comment: Did you try taking derivatives of an arbitrary function of $u$ and $x$ and seeing what happens?

Comment: That is a very good point. Might be enough to show that it's not possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this (using Lagrange notation): $u^{\prime\prime}(uu^{\prime})^{\prime}$?

That would give: $u^{\prime\prime}(u^{\prime}u^{\prime}+uu^{\prime\prime})=u^{\prime\prime}u^{\prime}u^{\prime}+u^{\prime\prime}uu^{\prime\prime}$

Comment: This wasn't what the OP was asking for though. Look at the form of the expressions he is trying to put his problem in.

Comment: Yes, I know. But still worth knowing if he's interested in this simplification or not. And technically I could derive a function $C$ such that the simplification I gave is equal to $C(u^{\prime\prime})$. $C$ would involve integration though...

Comment: I am looking for the specific simplification above. I suspect it is not all possible and the comment @Mattos may be enough to show that. I will try. Thank you anyway.

Comment: In the OP, $C$ is a function right? You could define $C(z)=z((\int\int z\ dx\ dx)(\int z\ dx))^{\prime}$ Then $C(u_{xx})=u_x^2u_{xx}+uu_{xx}^2$. $a$ and $b$ would be 1.

Comment: $C$ is a constant, just edited the question regarding this.

Comment: Oh, I see. The outer parenthesis are for raising expression to power of $b$. BTW, did you try any representative definitions of $u$ and see if they could be expressed in that form? You'd just need 1 counter example to show it wasn't possible.